# How does TypeScript allow assignment of null to type null[]?

Tags: typescript, null, undefined, tsc

I am learning typescript and I see a few counter-intuitive practices when it comes to `null` and `undefined`.

```
const a: null[] = null;
const b: null[] = [null];
const c: null[] = undefined;
const d: null[] = [undefined];
```

All the above statements do not cause any errors upon compiling. Although looking at it, it seems like it should be causing type errors. I have a feeling this has to do something with my understanding of `null` and `undefined`, but can someone please explain why this does not cause any errors and runs perfectly?

I thought it has something to do with not including `"strict": true` in `tsconfig.json`, but it seems to work even after including it.

EDIT: [image]

Comment: Which version of ts are U using? all except one statements cause errors
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhmArgGzQbQLowLzLpoDcMA9GTAKYBONINAUKJLAEZKoY74yZdpspCjBABrZuGgxgnIjwIowAEyoAzAJZgqy4ZVr0mLacrndcBTEtWbtyoeX10GQA

Comment: Seems to work with `strict: true` here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhmArgGzQbQLowLzLpoDcAUKJLAEZKoY74yZ1rZkXQzC1EMEpgAJgFMAZgEswwwe3CdBPergKYBIiVMFtSQA - `= null` and `= undefined` are not allowed. Nor is `= [undefined]`.

Comment: That's what I figured but it doesn't seem to cause issues for me. Please refer to the image I added just now.

Comment: 1. What are the tsconfig options you use? 2. Are you sure the tsconfig options you have *are* used?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `"strict": true` under `"compilerOptions"` fixed it.